# Showing the integers has the same cardinality to the Natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like just to check if my function which sends the positive integers numbers to the odd natural numbers and the non positive integers numbers to the even natural numbers is a bijection, more explicitly: $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb N, x\mapsto 2x-1$, if $x\gt0$ and $x\mapsto -2x$, if $x\le0$

I'm almost sure I'm right, it's just to be sure.

Thanks

Comment: It's correct. You need to prove it *is* bijective, though.

Comment: @egreg thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. 
Write up its inverse.