# How to prove that a function from N to Z is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{Z}$ and I think that by proving a function exists between $f(\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{Z}$ (that is onto and $1$-$1$) would show this.

However I'm at a loss at how to show this and I am wondering if someone could help me get a proof form of this?

Comment: Closely related, maybe duplicates http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795234/showing-the-integers-has-the-same-cardinality-to-the-natural-numbers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873927/how-to-show-the-integers-have-same-cardinality-as-the-natural-numbers

Comment: @Pp.. after your edit the question is quite difficult to understand. As the symbol ~ between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is not visible anymore. Please, try to be more careful in te future.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $k \mapsto k/2$ for $k$ even, and $k \mapsto -(k+1)/2$ for $k$ odd.

Comment: with a slight adjustment if $\mathbb N$ starts at $1$

Comment: Yes in that case replace the $+1$ by $-1$.